# Download files from object storage in visual app of Oracle Visual Builder. How to use data from ATP Database to get dinamically the name of the files

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db, oracle-integration-cloud

I am trying to download specific files from the Object Storage in the Oracle Cloud in my Oracle Visual Builder App (my visual builder is inside OIC, Oracle Integration Cloud).
[image]

I'd like to use the name of the "File URL" column (see the picture above) as the file name of the file to download from the Object storage, but this file name should be different from every download button (again in the picture above, you can see that every download button should download the file that has the name of the value of the "File URL" column). The File URL column is the field of a business object which is linked to the SDP variable and the data arrives from an ATP database that is inside the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. The column "First File" contains the Download buttons. In the properties of this button there is an ojAction event which is linked to an action chain (see picture below).
[image]

I followed this [guide](https://blogs.oracle.com/vbcs/post/upload-download-files-from-oci-storage-visual-builder) (Download from OCI Storage section) to download one file, but I mapped the "filename" input parameter with a fixed value (the name of an existing files inside the object storage). Now, I'd like to make the filename value dynamic, but I don't know how to create a variable that gathers all the values of the specific column (File URL) in the DB and how to pass the single value of this column to the filename parameter. I have tried to create an SDP type variable that gets only the File URL values, but it's not getting the values of the file names. Do you have suggestions or have you seen a guide that is maybe useful to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you can't retrive the specific file URL linked to the row button the user click in order to download the right file.

If that's the case, then instead of using a button, you could use the "first-selected-row" event linked to the table itself; that will pass all the values of the selected row as parameter, and will allow you to link "$variables.rowData.fileURL" or whatever the field is called to the REST call.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of the field in the selected row as shown here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/vbcs/post/accessing-selected-rows-values-in-a-tables-in-visual-builder
Or as shown here in the row level action section:
https://blogs.oracle.com/vbcs/post/advanced-capabilities-for-the-table-components-in-visual-builder-tips